# How to upload data offline data in firestore from Android Application?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, offline

I am trying to upload GPS data in every 30sec in my firestore. I would like to store the GPS data even if internet is turned off and push data on firestore once connection resumes. 
I even enabled **offine persistence**

```
if (upload_count == 30000) {
            NMEA.GPSPosition position = new NMEA.GPSPosition();
            GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(position.lat, position.lon);
            Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

            data.put(CAR_ID, "ST***3");
            data.put(TRIP_ID, "****");
            data.put(ServerTimeStamp, FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
            data.put(ELEVATION, position.altitude);
            data.put(GEOPOINT, geoPoint);
            data.put(SPEED, position.velocity);
            data.put(GPS_LOCKSTATUS, position.quality);
            data.put(GPS_SATELLITE_INVIEW, position.Satellites_In_View);
            data.put(TERRAIN_BUMP_COUNT, "None");
            data.put(BATTERY_SOC, BitwiseOperation.SOC);
            data.put(CHARGER_CONNECTED, BitwiseOperation.Charger_switch);
            data.put(AC_STATUS, RPI_UC.CoolingState);
            data.put(GPSDate, position.day);
            data.put(GPSTime, position.time);

            FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                    .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
                    .build();
            db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

 db.collection("NewGPSData").document().set(data)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Uploaded in 30 sec",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            upload_count = 0;
```

This is what I'm doing in my loop. But I can't see my offline data in my data. Do I need to do something else as well

Comment: You are using this code while offline, right? If you add a log statement right before `NMEA.GPSPosition position = new NMEA.GPSPosition();` is something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: I just added  a toast just before the line you mentioned and I can see that toast coming

Comment: But you are using this code while offline, right?

Comment: Yes I am using this code while offline

Comment: How are you checking the offline data?